# LINQ Enumerable Threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, foreach, enumerable.range

I'm trying to understand how LINQ deals with threading. The following code generates ThreadStateException "Thread has not been started". Why this happens?

```
        var threads = Enumerable.Range(0, 50).Select(x =>
                                                         {
                                                             Thread thread = new Thread(Method);
                                                             thread.Name = x.ToString();
                                                             return thread;
                                                         });


        foreach (var thread in threads)
        {
            thread.Start();
        }

        foreach (var thread in threads)
        {
            thread.Join();
        }

        Console.WriteLine(j);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is unrelated to threading. When enumeration `threads` the second time your query is executed a second time and creates a second set of threads.

So you `.Start` one set of threads, and `.Join` another. You need to eagerly evaluate the query once, and then cache the result.

```
IEnumerable<Thread> lazyThreads = Enumerable.Range(...
Thread[] threads=lazyThreads.ToArray();//Evaluate and store in an array
```

You can also write it as a single statement:

```
var threads = Enumerable.Range(1,50).Select(...).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 4):

The `threads` variable is a *query*, not a list of threads. Each time you iterate over it, you execute the query over again, so in the second case, you are calling `Join()` without calling `Start()`.

You can add `ToList()` at the end of the query to make it a list:

```
 var threads = Enumerable.Range(0, 50).Select(x =>{ ... }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are enumerating the lambda expression twice (lazy enumeration) - your second foreach is therefore iterating through different threads from the first.

Try

```
var threads = Enumerable.Range(0, 50).Select( ... ).ToList();

foreach(var thread in threads)
...
```

Calling ToList() will create a list with the threads over which you can subsequently enumerate multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you're not really exploring how LINQ deals with threading.  Rather, you're using link to save a few lines of code while dealing with threading yourself.

Beginning with .Net 4.0, LINQ does some neat threading help out of the box.  Investigate [Parallel LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688.aspx).  Also check out the [Parallel Extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_Extensions).

As for your old fashioned thread handling, with which you happen to be using LINQ, your problem actually does results from your use of LINQ.  You're problem has to do with [delayed execution](http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2008/04/07/linq-and-delayed-execution.aspx).  In debug mode, hover of the *threads* variable after that line is done.  You'll see it's a query, not a simple collection.  Every time you access this variable, it will get it's values afresh.

The fix is easy and very common:  Just add .ToList() at the end of the first line.  Your implicitly typed *threads* variable will then be a simple list, and behave as you expect.

```
var threads = Enumerable.Range(0, 50).Select(x =>
                                 {
                                     Thread thread = new Thread(Method);
                                     thread.Name = x.ToString();
                                     return thread;
                                 }).ToList();
```